# Python raw input function for tax calculation

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple calculator for working out the tax due on a salary. Please see the code below:

I keep getting this error and I don't know what is wrong, please help :) thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 13
    elif salary > 11000 and salary < 43000:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

CODE:

```
salary = raw_input ("What is your salary?")

print "So your gross annual salary is %r GBP" % (salary)
print "\nNow we need to calculate what your net salary is."

def taxes(salary):

    salary >= 0
    while true:
        if salary < 11000:
            tax = 0
    elif salary > 11000 and salary < 43000:
        tax = (0.2 * income) - 2200
    elif salary > 43000 and salary < 150000:
        tax = (0.4 * (salary - 43000)) + 6400
    elif salary > 150000:
        tax = ((salary - 150000) * 0.45) + 6400 + 42800
return tax
```

Comment: Your indentation is completely wrong here so we can't tell you what is wrong (unless this is really how it is written in your file). If it _is_ how it appears after Rawing's edit, then the problem is your `elif` is dedented outside your while loop so it _begins a new loop_. The SyntaxError, then, is that you can't start a loop with elif.

Comment: It looks like this is the actual indentation of OP's code. It produces the same exact error.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. The function now seems to run. However, when I enter a salary, the tax does not display. How can I get it to display? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to correct your code

step1 : the salary data type should be of int, to correct..use the following code

---

step 2: Indentation is compulsory in python, so indent your code very well

---

step 3: Add an else statement after the conditional statements

---

step 4: indent return statement

change your code to this one

```
salary = int(raw_input ("What is your salary?"))

print "So your gross annual salary is %r GBP" % (salary)
print "\nNow we need to calculate what your net salary is."

def taxes(salary):

    salary >= 0
    while true:
        if salary < 11000:
            tax = 0
        elif salary > 11000 and salary < 43000:
            tax = (0.2 * income) - 2200
        elif salary > 43000 and salary < 150000:
            tax = (0.4 * (salary - 43000)) + 6400
        elif salary > 150000:
           tax = ((salary - 150000) * 0.45) + 6400 + 42800
        else :
            tax = undefined
    return tax
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. The function now seems to run. However, when I enter a salary, the tax does not display. How can I get it to display? Thanks

Comment: to make the tax display... call the function and save it to a variable, then print the variable out e.g taxFunc = taxes(1000), print taxFunc.....that should work

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have already stated, your indentation is incorrect.  See below:

```
def taxes(salary):

    salary >= 0
    tax = 0
    if salary < 11000:
        tax = 0
    elif salary > 11000 and salary < 43000:
        tax = (0.2 * income) - 2200
    elif salary > 43000 and salary < 150000:
        tax = (0.4 * (salary - 43000)) + 6400
    elif salary > 150000:
        tax = ((salary - 150000) * 0.45) + 6400 + 42800
    print("Value of tax is: " + str(tax))
    return tax

salary = raw_input ("What is your salary?")

print "So your gross annual salary is %r GBP" % (salary)
print "\nNow we need to calculate what your net salary is."
print("\nHere is your net salary after taxes: %r" % (taxes(int(salary))))
```

With python, indentations are how you tell the interpreter which blocks of code fall where (unlike with Java for example with semicolons being the end of line delimiter).  By not indenting properly on your `elif` statements, you are essentially telling the program there is an `elif` without an `if` hence your syntax problem.

Comment: Also, it looks like `true` should be `True`, and I can't see an exit from the `while` loop (and it looks like the while loop is entirely redundant). The `return tax` also needs to be inside the function definition.

Comment: Completely missed that the code.  Updated the answer.  Good catch @Andrew

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. The function now seems to run. However, when I enter a salary, the tax does not display. How can I get it to display? Thanks

Comment: If you want to display the tax at any point you'd need to print it out like so: `print("Your current salary is" " + str(tax))`  Just put that line wherever you want to print the tax

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your comment. That does not seem to work. I get this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 20
    print("Your current salary is" " + str(tax))
                                               ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Also: NameError: name 'tax' is not defined

Comment: My mistake, had an extra quote in there.  Try this line to print instead `print("Your current salary is: " + str(tax))`  Totally my fault for that second quote before the plus sign.  Declare the tax variable outside of your conditionals, so right under salary for instance like so `tax = 0`.

Comment: Thanks, but if I define tax = 0, then tax always comes back as 0, rather than running through the function and calculating the tax payable given the salary ?

Comment: Set `tax=0` in the function (this is important to scope the variable) and fix your indent on the return statement.  It shouldn't be in line with the method definition, but rather have an indention in front of it.  That should fix the problem you are having.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what you mean, is it possible you can copy any paste the correct code so I can see it working, thanks again, Gordon

Comment: Modified the code in the answer to include the declaration of the tax variable, the print statement, and fixed the indentation on the return statement.  Hopefully that helps some :-)

Comment: I have run that code, but the tax amount still does not display. This is the result I get if I input a salary of 75000: What is your salary? 75000
So your gross annual salary is '75000' GBP

Now we need to calculate what your net salary is.
=> None

Comment: Ok, I've edited the code once again (seems to be a theme with me huh? :-P).  Basically, there was no call to the method that was created.  This makes a call to the taxes method.  Note that the "while" loop has been removed as it was infinite.

Answer (score 0):

That because there are indent error in line number 12, now you can just copy pust this :

note : `salary > 11000 and salary < 43000`    equivalent to  `11000 < salary < 43000`    in python:

```
salary = raw_input ("What is your salary?")

print "So your gross annual salary is %r GBP" % (salary)
print "\nNow we need to calculate what your net salary is."

def taxes(salary):


    while true:
        if salary < 11000:
            tax = 0         
        elif 11000 < salary < 43000:
            tax = (0.2 * income) - 2200
        elif salary > 43000 and salary < 150000:
            tax = (0.4 * (salary - 43000)) + 6400
        elif salary > 150000:
            tax = ((salary - 150000) * 0.45) + 6400 + 42800
    return tax
```

Comment: What exactly does `salary >= 0` attempt to do?  It compares the two sides and returns a boolean that isn't used.  So it should be removed

Comment: I can only presume that the OP is trying to use the `salary >= 0` to evaluate to `True`, though it doesn't really add anything at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for a note, I did not see it

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. The function now seems to run. However, when I enter a salary, the tax does not display. How can I get it to display? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It felt like there was a better way of doing this, so I came up with an alternative route:

```
tax_bands = [11000, 43000, 150000]
tax_amts = [0.2, 0.4, 0.45]
salary = 43001
```

Placing the thresholds and amounts into a list means that you can change them more easily if you need to.

The function below creates a list of the tax calculations, `tax_list`, and then a separate list of the maximum tax liability in each band called `max_tax` (the upper band has no maximum).
It then compares the values in the lists, and overwrites the `tax_list` if the corresponding value is larger than the maximum.
Then it calculates the sum of all values in `tax_list` greater than zero and returns it.

```
def taxes(salary, tax_bands, tax_amts):     

    tax_list = [(pct * (salary - band)) for (band, pct) in zip(tax_bands, tax_amts)] 
    max_tax = []
    for index, sal in enumerate(tax_bands[:-1]):
        max_tax.append(tax_bands[index + 1] - sal)
    max_tax = [segment * tax for segment, tax in zip(max_tax, tax_amts[:-1])]
    for index, value in enumerate(tax_list):
        try:
            if value > max_tax[index]:
                tax_list[index] = max_tax[index]
        except:
            pass
        tax_to_pay = sum([x for x in tax_list if x > 0])
    return tax_to_pay

print taxes(salary, tax_bands, tax_amts)

salary = input ("What is your salary?")

print "So your gross annual salary is %r GBP" % (salary)
print "\nYour net annual salary is: {} GBP".format(salary - taxes(salary, tax_bands, tax_amts))
```

To be super safe, you could also have the first line in the function call `int(salary)` using a `try except` just to check that it's the right type and that someone hasn't entered `43,000`.